# Mount cifs share with different machine users - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mount, samba, cifs

I have a ubuntu machine which has different users on it. I wonder if there is a way so I multiple users can login to the same cifs server share using their different ubuntu credentials and different cifs server credentials.

Currently if one of the machine users want to connect, he has to mount to a certain directory like this:

```
user1@ubuntumachine:~$ sudo mount -t cifs -o "username=serveruser1,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) //server-address/folder /mount/path_on_ubuntu
```

and if `user2` wants to mount he either has to mount into a different location or he needs to `umount` `user1` first. I wonder if there a way where `user1` and `user2` can mount into the same to the same directory `/mount/path_on_ubuntu`?

Comment: I guess [mount namespaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) may help you. But why is mounting at the same location so important?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Is it possible to show me an example showing how this can be done using mount namespaces please? as I checked the link but I'm kinda lost in it.

Comment: I have no experience with this so I can't help you right now. Maybe someone else will. Again (out of curiosity and to make sure there's no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here), why is mounting at the same location so important?

Comment: Samba using its own users database, you need to add samba user(s) with `smbpasswd` command (or on samba 4+ you can use `samba-tool user add someUser`)